# Does SendBird SDK support Swift?

Tags: swift, api, sdk, chat, sendbird

I’ve been looking for a chat API supports Swift.

I checked their github repo and the SDK seems to be written in Objective-C.

Not sure it’s compatible with Swift. Has any one tried SendBird SDK in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

SendBird supports Swift import.
You can just install SendBird SDK with CocoaPod and import it like this.

import SendBirdSDK

Also make sure the `use_frameworks!` line in your Podfile is uncommented otherwise you will have to use a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).